# Finding a specific option in a JSON Array (or how I should reformat my JSON file)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm rather new to JSON handling and am having quite a bit of difficulty trying to find a specific object from my json array using JArray.Parse().

I can parse the array perfectly, but I'm not really sure how to get the specific object in the array without iterating through it, and checking each object individually to find a match. Perhaps I could format my JSON file a little better, or even to combine the two JSON files in my project together.

Here are both of the JSON files:

knownshares.json

```
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Fileshare #1",
            "server": "file-server01",
            "folder": "shared-folder",
            "domain": "YOURDOMAIN"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Fileshare #2",
            "server": "file-server02",
            "folder": "shared-folder",
            "domain": "YOURDOMAIN"
        }
    ]
```

users.json:

```
    [
        {
            "username": "youruser",
            "fileshares": [
                "1F",
                "2G"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I was able to accomplish this before with

```
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(jsonString);
```

but I'd like to be able edit specific objects inside the file without reading and re-writing the entire file.

If you have any suggestions on how to better structure my JSon file, that would be helpful as well. I'm used to using a database and this project is not really in the right scope to load up sql lite or something of the sort, so i figured JSon would be the easiest.

Edit:

I guess its clear after reading everyone's responses that in JSON its not really possible to edit objects without overwriting the entire JSON file, i'm not worried that these files will be too large (maybe 80 users at most for now) and if worse comes to worse, i can timestamp the user objects and prune them after some time.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the question here. It sounds like you're successfully deserializing the JSON into a .NET object (in this case, a `List<User>`). Do you want to know how to find a specific object in that list using .NET? If that's the case, it doesn't really matter that you got it from JSON; the answer will be the same. I also don't see how the two files are related.

Comment: JSON is a data interchange format, not a database.  To my knowledge, there is no tool that allows you to edit JSON in place on a disk without reading and rewriting the entire file.  If you're looking to do that kind of thing, then you need a database like SQLite.

Comment: thanks for your comments guys, the users json file references the known shares json file by the "ID" in the fileshare array under users, 1F would refer to a fileshare with ID 1 mapped on drive letter F. If what you say is true, Rebuilding the file isnt really that difficult since i can just re-serialize the list and overwrite the file. I guess you guys confirmed my suspicions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use XML rather than JSON? I don't think so you can in easy way manage JSON file without parsing file to c# object. If file is small it takes not much time to parse it.

Edit:
c#

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var item = doc.Root.Elements("Product").Single(x => (string)x.Element("Title") == "p1").Element("Title");
item.SetValue("New_value");
doc.Save("file.xml");
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Title>p1</Title>
    <Description>Desc1</Description>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Title>p2</Title>
    <Description>Desc2</Description>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

Comment: Can you edit specific objects of XML rather than overwriting the entire file? I've never worked with XML

Comment: I edited my answer, i think that this code should changing only one node, but i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks for this, It really doesn't look much different than JSON, but it actually does look like its easier to store data like this in a json file. Thanks for the code, I think i'm going to give XML a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I have found Newtonsoft to be really helpful when using json. In the past I only used XML but since finding the Newtonsoft library I would much rather prefer to work with json. It makes it easy to serialize and deserialize your json objects.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Comment: I am using this library, its great. I'm trying to understand how to modify specific objects in my arrays.

Comment: LINQ would be my only other thought but again it requires you to deserialize it into objects, edit the object that needs to be edited, and then serialize it back to json if needed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197957(v=vs.95).aspx